# Excel файла не создается приложением ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis, iis-10

WinServer 2016 (Windows 10) + IIS 10 + MS Office 2010. 
Приложение asp.net не может создать **и (или)** сохранить Excel файл (txt файл тоже) в локальной папке (на другом диске). 
**При этом** уже существующий файл с таким именем удаляет, а в режиме разработки (запуск проекта из Visual Studio 2015) файл создается и удаляется.
Может кто сталкивался с подобным?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разрешения (Полный доступ для всех групп) для папки в которую пишется\удаляется файл.

UPD 0 - Код создания файла

```
 // Создать книгу и лист
            _Application excel = new Application();
            Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
```

UPD 1 - Не прокатило, txt-файл тоже не создает.

```
 // Сохранить файл и выйти из него
     try
{
    wb.SaveAs(path);
    File.Create(@"f:\testAutorep\234.txt");
}
catch
{
    File.Create(@"f:\testAutorep\123.txt");
}
```

UPD 2
При создании Excel файла - исключение:

> Приложению Microsoft Excel не удается открыть или
>   сохранить документы из-за нехватки памяти или места на диске. • Чтобы
>   освободить память, закройте ненужные книги или программы. • Чтобы
>   освободить место на диске, удалите с этого диска ненужные файлы

РЕШЕНО - https://bloglisa.ru/?p=1419
Решение: Зайти в редактор реестра, найти раздел HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsof t\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders, в данном разделе найдите параметр “Cache” и измените его, например, на c:\temp (каталог temp на диске C: должен присутствовать). После изменения перезагружать компьютер не обязательно.

P.S. Если данный вариант не поможет, то попробуйте изменить переменные окружения (системные и пользовательские) temp и tmp на c:\temp

Comment: ну а ошибку то пишет какую?

Comment: да и код в студию генерации документа, плюс путь к папке. Может пишете не туда, куда хотите

Comment: варианты 1) excel не установлен. 2)Разрядность  Application не совпадает с разрядностью программы. (это если application instance не создаётся) 3)другое, в коде не показано как именно идёт выгрузка - не показан приличный кусок кода. Возможно там ошибка.

Comment: При запуске из студии все ок - удаляет имеющийся файл и пишет такой же но новый. Как с этим жить?)))))

Comment: Тащить на сервер приложения такую дырявую и тормозную зависимость, как Office-не есть гуд. Используйте EpPlus.

Comment: txt тоже не создает.....

Comment: проблема в пользователе из под которого работает iis. попробуйте работать в папке приложения. обычно создают каталог App_Data и в нем уже сохраняют файлы (необходимо дать также права на запись в этом каталоге)

Comment: Не используйте аболютные пути, только относительные. Представьте, что вы залили свой сайт на хостинг. Там может и не быть диска f. А главное, вам никто не позволит получить доступ к нему. Поэтому только пути, относительные к папке вашего веб-приложения.

Comment: При запуске проекта из Студии все ок, путь работает.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что "решено", но ответа не дано.

Comment: Если нашли решение, то опубликуйте ответ к вопросу. И нажмите галочку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: Зайти в редактор реестра, найти раздел HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsof t\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders, в данном разделе найдите параметр “Cache” и измените его, например, на c:\temp (каталог temp на диске C: должен присутствовать). После изменения перезагружать компьютер не обязательно.

P.S. Если данный вариант не поможет, то попробуйте изменить переменные окружения (системные и пользовательские) temp и tmp на c:\temp